# Disable mouse click outside cropped region

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcrop

I'm trying to use jquery jcrop to crop images.

this code starts the plugin adding some selected area to the image with aspcet ratio.

```
$('#cropbox').Jcrop(
{
setSelect:   [ 100, 100, 50, 50 ],
aspectRatio: 16 / 9
});
```

But if user clicks mouse on image somewhere else, the selection disappears. So what I want is to disable mouse clicks in this plugin so selected area will remain over the image.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SOLUTION

I've received email on my request to the creators of jcrop and that solved the problem

Here is the solution

First there must be some setSelect , so some area is always selected from the beginning.

And this `allowSelect: false` prevents mouse clicks, and keeps selected area always over the image.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#cropbox').click(function(){
    return false;
})
```

or

```
$('#cropbox').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: "e.preventDefault" should be "e.preventDefault()" to actually call the method.

Comment: not working guys, strange I put alert in both ways and no action at all