# Best Way For keep image from copying

Tags: html

We have a picture on Our website how can i prevent other users cant download this picture ?

is it possible or not ? if its not possible please give some ways to make harder the way of copy a picture

Comment: By the way it's impossible. What can you do versus a print screen ?

Comment: You can't prevent something from being copied, when published on the internet. I can use view-source, and evade any crafty solutions you invent.

Comment: i know but by print screen they can have my image quality

Comment: @babakfaghihian They will have the same image quality, trust me. Even if it's 10000000x1000000 it's possible to get the same quality with a print screen and the same size. You wanna hide the source ? Alright, I'll use cURL to parse your page.

Comment: This question is completely amibigious — I read **keep image from copying on another word** to be a wrapping issue? Babak, please edit the question for clarity & give code examples if relevant.

Comment: If you can see the image, you can copy it. Therefore, the only way to not have your image copied is to not show it.

Comment: you may try hotlinking protection

Comment: @DavidBélanger: I guess in the unlikely event you're copying a high-res image, like 300dpi, you'll lose quality :)

Comment: You can't copy-protect an image.  And you should *thank heavens* that nobody's crippled image formats with the same kind of DRM junk that's afflicted other media (I'm looking at you, Apple ;))

Comment: You can also try to embed them in flash like flickr do.

Comment: You first have to ask yourself why people are stealing your images? Is it a photography website? Have you considered watermarking the images themselves, or displaying a lower resolution? Basically, you're trying to solve the wrong problem — if I can view the image on my screen, consider it copiable

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to prevent someone from stealing a picture, someone refer to someone that is bad with technology, here's some technic :

- Place the image as CSS background instead
- Put a transparent DIV over the image.
- Disable right click
- Watermark all your image
- Disable direct image access
- Use .htaccess to allow only your website to access your image
- Embed the picture using flash or something similar

Consider this : what is on the Internet will be and always be "free" to every "thief".

**EDIT** Here's a technic used to convert torrent inside a PNG : http://stegtorrent.sourceforge.net/ You could do the reverse if your the FBI ! :) Store your image inside a diffrent type of file.

Comment: @David_Belanger very well said.These are more important than disabling the mouse click :) +1

Comment: @David_Belanger and a vote up too from my side. This information must be considered by all web designers. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The user can copy it one way or another. One interesting way though is to use images as CSS background that makes it it a little harder than right click and save image.

```
<div style="background-image:theimage.png ;"></div>
```

But to the determined user there is not much you can do. when you share an image just assume someone will copy it. Otherwise don't share it.

Comment: Even a user who isn't computer savvy enough to check HTML source can still do 'Save background image as…', unless you also put something in the div to mask the background from selection.

Comment: @anotherdave the image can simply be in the css, i put it inline to make it simpler. Everyday users dont spend much time scouting CSS files. if they know what css is in the first place

Comment: With Firefox, right-click on any section of a site that has a background image (even via an external stylesheet) and you get an option in the context menu 'View background image…'. Choosing this will open the image in a new tab, ready to download.

Answer (score 0):

Add this script to the body tag. This will disable the right click from which save is called.
Have a look at this post on stack overflow [Disable mouse click outside cropped region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152517/disabling-mouse-clicks-on-image-while-using-jquery-jcrop)

Comment: Too much complicated. With jQuery : `$(document).live("contextmenu",function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
});`

Comment: Overcomplicated Javascript.  Code bloat.  Slows the web page.  And there's *STILL* nothing preventing me from finding and downloading the image if I really want it :)

Comment: @DavidBélanger Hehehehe :D Actually I too hate that snippet and prefer yours but there was no tag about JQuery mentioned otherwise would have loved to give it in that way. Thats why I used plain JS.

Comment: @ShivKumarGanesh You win a +1 here, you are right !

Comment: @paulsm4 it was just for disabling the right click now use either `$('#image - id').click(function(){
    return false;
})` or `$(document).live("contextmenu",function(e){ e.preventDefault() }); `